# Create multiple image attribute Magento

Tags: image, magento, attributes, product

Hi i am very confused in **achieving a task** which is, in magento i need  an image attribute like a colour, I mean 
I need to show a image instead of text for a colour attribute.  I need that image selected as a colour if a user clicks on that image and I can also get the value in a cart. Please suggest how can i do this.

I was thinking of showing related products there but the client says he
doesn't want to show a related products there, in that case he needs to
add more products.

He wants the user to select the colour as an image with attribute,
Please suggest to me how can I do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Varius color-size swatch extension are available for that.
This is a simple and free extension [Gala Color Swatch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-9787.html)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, if this is the case, when each product color variant is in real another stock item (like the shoes etc..) it means, if someone wants to change color or size, exactly needs change an item, not only item attribute.

In the future customer will face the problem in stock qty of colored items. When you do not have specific color on store, you must remove that attribute, and you cant say: In red we have qty2, in blue we have qty4.
If some item in red color will have another price etc...
In attribute named color, you cant remove used colors, that means, if one item haven't in blue color, second item have and they share one attribute, you cant not delete blue color.
That means hundreds of colors in best case.

This is most important and you must consider this.

**Right solution for this is to manage a Bundeld Products, default product is completed from product represents color variants.**

But you can use extension described by Deependra Singh.

Comment: HI i am impressed with the thinking and i will surely suggest this to my client .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rihit,

You can update items options in cart as described in following link:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/updating-options-of-configurable-product-that-is-already-in-the-cart/

If you follow this link you can update cart, but i faced one problem in this, that is if you add same product to cart after item update in cart, the product will add as new product (It wont merge) otherwise it works well.

I can suggest that just use this to get options of product in cart and update items using "cart/updateOptions" this you can see in cart edit item page. You need to send what params are sending along with updateOptions link in edit view. You can check this in updateOptions() in Mage/Checkout/controllet/cart.php.

this will support update only one item at a time.

The remaining thing that showing colors and selecting color those you can handle through css and javascript.

thank you,
Narendra

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```html
<a href="jeans1-big.jpg" class="MagicZoom" id="jeans"><img src="jeans1-small.jpg" /></a>

<a data-zoom-id="jeans" href="jeans1-big.jpg" data-image="jeans1-small.jpg"><img src="jeans1-tiny.jpg" /></a>
<a data-zoom-id="jeans" href="jeans2-big.jpg" data-image="jeans2-small.jpg"><img src="jeans2-tiny.jpg" /></a>
<a data-zoom-id="jeans" href="jeans3-big.jpg" data-image="jeans3-small.jpg"><img src="jeans3-tiny.jpg" /></a>
<a data-zoom-id="jeans" href="jeans4-big.jpg" data-image="jeans4-small.jpg"><img src="jeans4-tiny.jpg" /></a>
<a data-zoom-id="jeans" href="jeans5-big.jpg" data-image="jeans5-small.jpg"><img src="jeans5-tiny.jpg" /></a>
```

you can look [gallery](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration) and try to hover on images